# Scroll position bug on one page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scrolltop, scrollto

I'm having an issue whereby the scroll position isn't going to the corresponding section of the page when being reference as an external link.

For example, when trying to access this raw URL http://wp.themechills.com/eternity/#rsvp the idea would be for the page to load on that section. What happens though, is it scrolls up to be in between the Groomsmen and Gifts section.

This same link, works perfectly when being used from the websites side navigation. For example go to http://wp.themechills.com/eternity/, then click the RSVP menu item and you will see it does in fact go to the corresponding section.

I have checked to see if there are any JS or other errors on the page, but there doesn't appear to be any.

Can anyone assist with this?

Thanks in advance.

Leo

=============================================================================

## Code Example

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
function onePageNav(){
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Smooth Scroll
    /*  Thanks to: https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $(".nav").onePageNav({
        filter: ':not(.external)',
        changeHash: false,
        scrollSpeed: 1500,
    });
}

onePageNav();

function smoothScroll(){

    // Scrolls to RSVP section
    $(".js-scroll").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#rsvp").offset().top
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    });

    return false;
}

smoothScroll();
```

});

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    if(window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(jQuery('a[href="#'+hash+'"]','#menu-primary').length>0){
      jQuery('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: jQuery("#"+hash).offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same functionality as working with menu click, you can trigger the menu click event after jQuery events `page load` or `document ready`, So when page gets you can check the `hash` in `URL` and can trigger the menu with same `href`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
      if(jQuery('a[href="#'+hash+'"]','#menu-primary').length>0){
        jQuery('a[href="#'+hash+'"]','#menu-primary').trigger('click');
      }
  }
});
```

Or you can try this one to find the correct element position and then scroll to same section:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(jQuery('a[href="#'+hash+'"]','#menu-primary').length>0){
      jQuery('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: jQuery("#"+hash).offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
});
```

on window load:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(jQuery('a[href="#'+hash+'"]','#menu-primary').length>0){
      jQuery('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: jQuery("#"+hash).offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks @lokeshpaha, though it's not that I want the same functionality, it's that I need the same positioning. When I first go to /#rsvp, it goes to the corresponding section, but if I try to go there again, it goes to the section and then scroll upwards.

It's as though it is unable to find the accurate position on the page.

Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks @lokeshpahal - still no luck. Seems to still be scrolling to the gifts section versus RSVP.  

Would it help to add my existing JS to the thread?

Comment: would you please show your code that you have written for this functionality.

Comment: Added the code block with your example included as well @lokeshpahal

Comment: try to run the same on `window.load` event.

Comment: So I tweaked the code as above. Still same result. Have I done this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads it does position where the RSVP section is at that time. The problem is that this does not take in effect the height of all the images. Before the images load, we will say, the RSVP section is at 500px down the page. After the images load, total images height equal 1000px, now the RSVP section is around 1500px. To view the page loading play the [video here](http://www.webpagetest.org/video/view.php?id=140801_SR_5X9.1.1). As you can see it does do as it is supposed to then the rest loads. There are a few ways to fix this.

1) The script that scrolls to that section, make sure it executes on document ready. This may not work if there is a lazy loader or images are loaded by scripts or after document is ready. If images are loaded by scripts, the one page nav would have to be one of the last calls in document ready to work properly.

2) use jQuery(window).load(function() {}) - This waits for all images, frames, and objects to load. This still may have an impact that may not work properly if any images or elements are increased in size after the document has fully loaded.

3) Make sure all images/divs/spans/sections/etc... are loaded with a height. This will act like a placeholder and push the RSVP to the correct position. Quick look showed at least 5 images did not have a set height. This will not take into affect any images that are loaded by JS

Comment: How could you tell which images did not have a set height @James?

Comment: looked at the raw source being returned from the server. The ones that I found quickly were your logos @ThemeChills

Comment: And you mean to define the height in the image element or through css? Which solution would you propose @James?

Comment: Best would be through html just incase the CSS is not loaded when it fires the scrollTop

Comment: The problem is that the user may add logos which have different heights, therefore I can't really be hard coding this, thoughts? In fact here is an example of a site that doesn't specify heights for some of their assets, though the scrolling position works as expected http://demo.drythemes.com/dry-wp-one-page/

Comment: Hence the first solution. Since the code is in a document ready or on load, may want to include a wait/sleep prior to firing or make it the last script to load. The script is working as designed, it is just the images that are loading after the fact.

Comment: I thought I was doing this. If you see the code block, the script is only run on document ready or am I missing something? In addition, I also load all custom script in the footer of the page. Did I structure this incorrectly @James?

Comment: You still have 3 scripts loaded after your *custom.js*. 

jQuery(window).load runs a bit after jQuery(document).ready  

.load waits for the complete page load (images/iframes/objects) only option I have to try.

Comment: Thanks @James - so you are saying to change from document.ready to .load, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use this and it will scroll you to whatever the scroll location of your element with id rsvp.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var offset = $("#rsvp").offset();
    $("body, html").animate({scrollTop:offset.top-10});

})
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexdn, though the problem is not on the click event but on the initial page load. If I go to http://wp.themechills.com/eternity/#rsvp it does not scroll to the corresponding section. I think it does have to do with the images not being loaded yet, though can't work out the implementation...

Comment: Then just set the .ready event to document...Check the code above, I just edit it...

Comment: Thanks @Alexdn - the issue actually happens across all external URLs, RSVP was just an example, so the same would apply to the /#gifts for example. Therefore I would need to find a solution which is dynamic to any URL path that is referenced. Hope that makes sense.